# Is there a way to use higher order abstract syntax with linear types?

Tags: binders

Is there a way to use HOAS style with linear types?

I'm also interested in affine types or other substructural systems.

I vaguely recall there has been some work for embedded DSLs for Haskell but I'm not sure if it would work just as fine for theorem proving.

I have a hunch you could do something like

```
Record Iso A B := {
  to: A -> B ;
  from: B -> A ;
  to_from x: to (from x) = x ;
  from_to x: from (to x) = x ;
}.
Class Linear (T: Set) := {
  lam: Iso T T -> T ;
  app: T -> T -> T ;
}.
```

But it seems a bit awkward to use in practice. I think that's probably the major problem with this kind of approach. Any encoding is going to be pretty heavy weight and not necessarily better than just using a typing context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The basic idea is to give a HOAS encoding, and then define an auxiliary judgement which checks that variables are used linearly inside a term. Then your typing judgement has additional premises which check whether the term is being used linearly.

[The Twelf wiki shows how to do it here](http://twelf.org/wiki/Linear_logic).

Comment: Thank you . For some reason your link is broken but I was able to search up the page anyway. I played a bit with this sort of approach but it's a bit clumsy in Coq. https://gist.github.com/mstewartgallus/052eabf8044e23ecfb678bf92931d9d8

Comment: I'd guess the problem with the link is that `twelf.org` does not support `https:` (only `http:`).